# How to resolve python thread error 'too many arguments' on my created web crawler?

Tags: python

I get an error when i run my code.

[image]

It gives a thread error:

> too many arguments

I am trying to get it to go through every link it finds, it's a webcrawler.
I don't know what I did wrong. Please let me know if you have an idea.

```
    def run(links):
    try:
        try:
            import random
            z = str(links[random.randint(0,len(links))]).replace("(","")
            q = z.replace(")","")
            m = q.replace(", 'http'","")
            m = m[1:len(m)-1]
            line = m
        except:
            with open("sites.txt", "r") as file:
                import random
                line = random.choice(file.readlines())
                print(line)
        with urllib.request.urlopen(line) as response:
            html = response.read()

        #use re.findall to get all the links
        links = re.findall('"((http|ftp)s?://.*?)"', str(html))
        a = 0
        print(links)
        with open("sites.txt", "a") as file:
            while a != len(links):
                z = str(links[a]).replace("(","")
                q = z.replace(")","")
                m = q.replace(", 'http'","")
                m = m[1:len(m)-1]
                l = m
                t = threading.Thread(target=run, args=l)
                t.start()
                file.write(m + "\n")
                a += 1
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        pass
import urllib.request
import re
import traceback
import threading
go = False
l = None
t = threading.Thread(target=run, args=l)
while go != True:
    afd = input()
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(afd) as response:
            html = response.read()
            go = True
    except:
        print("Error\nmake sure your using \nhttp://www.\nor https://www.\nor the ip")
with open("sites.txt", "a") as file:
    file.write(afd + "\n")

#use re.findall to get all the links
links = re.findall('"((http|ftp)s?://.*?)"', str(html))
a = 0
print(links)
with open("sites.txt", "a") as file:
    while a != len(links):
        z = str(links[a]).replace("(","")
        q = z.replace(")","")
        m = q.replace(", 'http'","")
        m = m[1:len(m)-1]
        file.write(m + "\n")
        a += 1
while True:
    try:
        try:
            import random
            z = str(links[random.randint(0,len(links))]).replace("(","")
            q = z.replace(")","")
            m = q.replace(", 'http'","")
            m = m[1:len(m)-1]
            line = m
        except:
            with open("sites.txt", "r") as file:
                import random
                line = random.choice(file.readlines())
                print(line)
        with urllib.request.urlopen(line) as response:
            html = response.read()

        #use re.findall to get all the links
        links = re.findall('"((http|ftp)s?://.*?)"', str(html))
        a = 0
        print(links)
        with open("sites.txt", "a") as file:
            while a != len(links):
                z = str(links[a]).replace("(","")
                q = z.replace(")","")
                m = q.replace(", 'http'","")
                m = m[1:len(m)-1]
                l = m
                t = threading.Thread(target=run, args=l)
                t.start()
                file.write(m + "\n")
                a += 1
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when creating the `Thread` object you shuold pass the arguments not as a list. but as a tuple.

like this:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=run, args=(l,))
t.start()
```

this will solve your error.

BTW - since you are using python to crawl webpages. I would strongly recommend using [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)

Comment: When i run this i get a lot of errors saying  ' ' is not a valid  URL, but i can tell some part of it are working, the file is getting bigger.

Comment: this is a new other problem. the threads are running. probobly some of the URL's they are trying to download are not valid..

Comment: yeah that makes sense. I looked a little bit more into the errors and that's exactly why there happening. Now it works great!

Comment: added a strong recommendation to use `scrapy` in the answer. you should check it out.